# Can I compare the text of a button with array elements in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter the photographs on my project when I click on the filter button

(Each of my photographers has his own TAGS in my JSON file, so i want to compare the text of my clicked button and see if it matches of any of the TAGS and display only the photographs who corresponds to this button)

My project looks like this -> [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUHUS.jpg)

I don't know if my logic is good for this action, so if you have any idea of how I could do this it would be GREAT

This is my code

```
/*Loop throughe each photographe and create a new div then fill this div with photographer's inforamtions*/
function displayPhotographers(dataJson){
  document.querySelectorAll(".filters_container span").forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    
    dataJson.photographers.forEach(photographe => { 
      const photographersDiv = document.getElementById('container');
      const div = document.createElement("div");     
      
      photographersDiv.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="photographerContainer ${photographe.tags.join(" ")}" }>
            <div class="portraitBox">
              <img src="${photographe.portrait}" alt="photo">
            </div>
            <h1 class="name">${photographe.name}</h1>
            <p class="city">${photographe.city}, ${photographe.country}</p>
            <p class="tagline">${photographe.tagline}</p>
            <p class="price">${photographe.price}€/jour</p>
            <p class="tags">${photographe.tags.map(tag => `<span class="tag">${tag}</span>`).join(" ")}</p>  
        </div>
        `   
    }); 

  }));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tag classes to every photo div (along with photographerContainer).

```
<div class="photographerContainer ${photographe.tags.join(" ")}">
          <div class="portraitBox">
            <img src="${photographe.portrait}" alt="photo">
          </div>
          <h1 class="name">${photographe.name}</h1>
          <p class="city">${photographe.city}, ${photographe.country}</p>
          <p class="tagline">${photographe.tagline}</p>
          <p class="price">${photographe.price}€/jour</p>
          <p class="tags">${photographe.tags.map(tag => `<span class="tag">${tag}</span>`).join(" ")}</p>  
      </div>
```

If a filter is clicked, loop over all the photographerContainer elements and check if the element has a tag which is clicked, if it doesn't have that tag add a class which hides that div (like [visibility:hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)) .
In the case of unselecting the tag, loop over all the tag elements and remove the class which modifies the visibility.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i can't add classes to my elements because i have a Dynamic HTML, i have a JSON file so the date grabed from the json file are being stored inide a Template Literal, i don't think it gona work this way :/

Comment: I think you can access the tags in the photographe, I have edited my post to demonstrate that. please check

Comment: Thank you for your Update, now is much better the usage of an expression will grab every tag of every photographer and it gonna use them as classes. If it is not to much to ask, can you show me what condition can i use ? i updated my code you can go and see it, i created a function that will loop every button and inside ov it  I'v puted the template literals...

Comment: the photographers foreach shouldn't be the onclick callback. I created a small codesandbox for with 1 filter. you can get an idea of how it could be implemented https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-paper-w4tij